# Is it possible to create a user input number pyramid whereby the pyramid only display from 0 - 9?

Tags: c, loops

I tried editing the loop for counter so that the last line of `printf` is non negative but I'm not too sure which part of the loop to edit.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printPatternHere(int height);

int main() {
    int height;
    printf("Enter the number of rows: ");
    scanf("%d", &height);
    printf("printPattern: \n");
    printPatternHere(height);
    return 0;
}

void printPatternHere(int height) {
    int n, c, row, t = 1;
    int counter = 0;

    for (row = 1; row <= height; row++) {

        for (c = 1; c <= height - row; c++)
            t = row; // start each line with row number

        for (c = 1; c <= row; c++) {
            counter++;

            if (counter > 9) {
                t = t % 10;
            }

            printf("%d ", t);
            t++;
        }

        for (c = 1 ; c < row; c++) {
            t--; //reset row number
        }

        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

If userinput is 14, its output should be something like this:

```
1 
2 3 
3 4 5 
4 5 6 7 
5 6 7 8 9 
6 7 8 9 0 1 
7 8 9 0 1 2 3 
8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 
9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 
2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 
3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 
4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

Comment: `void printline(int n) { printf("%d", n % 10); for (k = 1; k < n; k++) printf(" %d", (n + k) % 10); puts(""); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function is cluttered too much, for loops are more than enough. Code below will be enough. Better to debug to grasp the idea.

```
// in "main"
    printPattern3(height); // wrong function name!
    printPatternHere(height); // corrected.
```

```
void printPatternHere(int height) {
    int c, row;

    for (row = 1; row <= height; row++) {
        for (c = 0; c < row; c++) {
            printf("%d ", (c + row) % 10);
        }

        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but im new to C programming, what programme do you reccommend to debug? im currently using codeblocks.

Comment: I do use CodeBlocks as well.

Comment: alright i'll try to meddle with it around more... thanks alot!

Comment: @MTee : And one more point; you'd better enclose `for` & `if` blocks in braces even if they contain just a single line. That way, you would have realized that your second `for` loop is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is too complicated. The output of the pyramid can be done simpler.

For example this loop

```
    for (c = 1; c <= height - row; c++)
        t = row; // start each line with row number
```

does not make a sense.

Here you are.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    while ( 1 )
    {
        const unsigned int Base = 10;
        
        printf( "Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): " );
        
        unsigned int n;
        
        if ( scanf( "%u", &n ) != 1 || n == 0 ) break;
        
        putchar( '\n' );
        
        for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        {
            for ( unsigned int j = 0; j < i + 1; j++ )
            {
                printf( "%u ", ( j + i + 1 ) % Base );
            }
            
            putchar( '\n' );
        }
        
        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 14

1 
2 3 
3 4 5 
4 5 6 7 
5 6 7 8 9 
6 7 8 9 0 1 
7 8 9 0 1 2 3 
8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 
9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 
2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 
3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 
4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 0
```

If you want to write a separate function that will output the pattern then the program can look the following way.

```
#include <stdio.h>

FILE * display_pyramid( unsigned int n, FILE *fp )
{
    const unsigned int Base = 10;
        
    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        for ( unsigned int j = 0; j < i + 1; j++ )
        {
            fprintf( fp, "%u ", ( j + i + 1 ) % Base );
        }
            
        fputc( '\n', fp );
    }
    
    return fp;
}

int main(void) 
{
    while ( 1 )
    {
        printf( "Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): " );
        
        unsigned int n;
        
        if ( scanf( "%u", &n ) != 1 || n == 0 ) break;
        
        putchar( '\n' );
        
        fputc( '\n', display_pyramid( n, stdout ) );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! works well but im still trying to grasp the concept